# Why does the following snippet of code output 3?

Tags: c++

Why does the following snippet of code output 3?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout <<    + '+'    - '-'    * '*'    / '/'  << std::endl;
}
```

GCC output [here.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d8af88cf64ad891)
Same output for Clang as well.

Comment: Convert those characters into integral values corresponding to ASCII encoding. Then you will have your answer.

Comment: Characters in C++ are numbers. You can look up there values here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Already did that.

Comment: @P.W What's left to explain then?

Comment: The output is 3 on your ASCII system, but -13 on my EBCDIC system.

Comment: I did not do it for my own sake. Thought it would​ be a helpful q&a for those who might come across such snippets involving ASCII values. All I got for my effort was downvotes. :-)

Comment: As many think this is a bad question, I request the moderators to close/delete this question. Please see my comments above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'` and `'/'` are `char` types - which means they are integral types and support arithmetic operations. Each of those have numeric representation, which is defined by encoding. In most of the cases nowadays, the encoding is `ASCII`. In ASCII encoding, `*` is 42, `-` is 45, `+` is 43 and `/` is 47.

Taking this into account, your code is equivalent to

```
std::cout << +43 - (45 * 42 / 47)  << std::endl;
```

And that is obviously 3 in integer arithmetic, when `(45 * 42 / 47)` is equal to 40.

Comment: This question has received close votes as many consider it a bad question. So it may be closed/deleted. However, I will accept this answer.